# C# System.NotSupportedException when reading a byte from string

Tags: c#

I was wondering if anyone can help me on this one, I've search the whole internet and I can't seem to find any solution, I want to read byte from a txt file, at first i use string array to get the files that end with `.txt`, follow by converting string array to string and use the string to read all bytes and place it in byte array. But when I run the program it come out an exception stating `System.NotSupportedException`. Can anyone help?

```
 String[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\feature", "*.txt");
        String file = ConvertStringArrayToString(fileArray);
Byte[] pFeatureLib = File.ReadAllBytes(file); // error occur here


  public String ConvertStringArrayToString(String[] array)
  {
        // Concatenate all the elements into a StringBuilder.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string value in array)
        {
            builder.Append(value);
            builder.Append('.');
        }
        return builder.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: If there is more than 1 text file you're not going to get a single file name in your file variable.. but an invalid name.

Comment: OT are you sure you want to read *bytes* from a *txt* file? There is also a `File.ReadAllText` or `File.ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an array of files - means you get multiple files.

The code should be:

```
String[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\feature", "*.txt");
foreach(string file in fileArray){
     Byte[] pFeatureLib = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
}
```

or if you want only the first file (for any reason):

```
String[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\feature", "*.txt");
if(fileArray.Length > 0) {
    Byte[] pFeatureLib = File.ReadAllBytes(fileArray[0]);
}
```